Two binary operations which do not distribute but do reverse-distribute
The distributive property of ordered pairs $(*_1,*_2)$ of binary operations is very well-known. I define the reverse-distributive property as this equation: $x *_1 (y *_2 z) = (x *_1 z) *_2 (x *_1 y)$. My question is, is there a set with two binary operations $*_1$ and $*_2$ such that $*_1$ reverse-distributes over $*_2$, but does not distribute over it? I have tried to come up with such binary operations, but with no luck. A necessary condition is that $*_2$ is not commutative, but that is far from sufficient.

Observation: if $*_1 = \boxtimes$ is associative, then we have $(w\boxtimes x)\boxtimes(y\boxplus z)= (w\boxtimes x)\boxtimes(z\boxplus y)$, so $\boxtimes$ must lose quite a bit of information (in particular, there cannot be a multiplicative identity).

Let $(X,\cdot)$ be a semigroup with an anti-homomorphism $i\colon X\to X$ (meaning $i(x\cdot y) = i(y)\cdot i(x)$) which is not a homomorphism. For example, take $X$ to be any non-commutative group such as $S_3$ and $i(x) = x^{-1}$. Then take the two binary operations

$x *_1 y := i(y)$
$x *_2 y := x\cdot y$

Then your reverse-distributive property is true precisely because $i$ is an antihomomorphism, and the distributive property fails because it is not a homomorphism.
